# trigger.io "The binary being analyzed must be an executable" itune issue

Tags: itunes, trigger.io, submission

I went to upload my ipa as I normaly do and after upload it via itunes I got this email

The binary being analyzed must be an executable: /tmp/mz_3482061619165087240dir/conbop-1377470196-1.ipa/Payload/device-ios.app/Forge

The file 'device-ios.app/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png' is labeled as a PNG file, but is not valid to that format; file command reports: './device-ios.app/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png: JPEG image data, EXIF standard '

The file 'device-ios.app/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png' is labeled as a PNG file, but is not valid to that format; file command reports: './device-ios.app/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png: JPEG image data, EXIF standard '

The file 'device-ios.app/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png' is labeled as a PNG file, but is not valid to that format; file command reports: './device-ios.app/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png: JPEG image data, EXIF standard '

The file 'device-ios.app/Default-Portrait~ipad.png' is labeled as a PNG file, but is not valid to that format; file command reports: './device-ios.app/Default-Portrait~ipad.png: JPEG image data, EXIF standard '

The file 'device-ios.app/Default@2x~iphone.png' is labeled as a PNG file, but is not valid to that format; file command reports: './device-ios.app/Default@2x~iphone.png: JPEG image data, EXIF standard '

The file 'device-ios.app/Default~iphone.png' is labeled as a PNG file, but is not valid to that format; file command reports: './device-ios.app/Default~iphone.png: JPEG image data, EXIF standard '

Any help would be appreciated as to why itunes is kicking this back.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did have to change the images as well as do some other things with permissions. Connorhd explained in this post how to change the permissions for the time being.

[The binary being analyzed must be an executable trigger.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551998/the-binary-being-analyzed-must-be-an-executable-trigger-io)

Answer (score 1):

The image errors are because Apple require all the images are png files rather than jpgs, they appear to have recently become more strict about enforcing this which might be why you haven't had these problems before, you should be able to resave the files as png with an image editor.

I've not seen the binary is not an executable error before, I'd recommend trying again once you fix the image issues, if you still see that error it would be great if you could send your ipa file to support@trigger.io and we'll take a look at it.

Comment: ok, well let me ask this questions then. Trigger.io apps duplicate the images for the splash screen causing a file to be double the size. I had posted a questions about this a while back and there at the time there was no way to prevent this. If I use a png (even 8bit ) my larger ipad files are 400k vs 68k jpg. I cant afford to have an ipa be 20 megs to download seems very excessive.