# The binary being analyzed must be an executable trigger.io

Tags: ios, trigger.io

This seems to be a proble with permissions on how forge packages the IPA ( wild guess )

anyhow I also found that phonegap build users are [having the same issue](http://forums.adobe.com/message/5640139)

I'm using Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Apple might have changed their validation for IPA files, Trigger will have to look into this and update the way IPAs are created.

In the mean time IPAs are actually just zip files, you should be able to unzip it, make the Forge binary executable and zip it back up. I've not tried this so it might not work, but its worth a try until there is a better fix.

To do so using a command line on a mac you should be able to run the following commands (I assume you have access to a mac to use application loader). `bad.ipa` is the ipa file you tried to submit which didn't work, and good.ipa is the resulting ipa file which you should hopefully be able to submit.

```
unzip bad.ipa
chmod a+x Payload/device-ios.app/Forge
zip -r good.ipa Payload
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give executable permission mentioned file trigger.io

This is what i did when i have same issue with google Admob library

> chmod +x libGoogleAnalytics_debug.a

and compile again and upload ipa back to itunes connect.

Comment: I am not using a mac to compile so my souce is sent to forge and then sent back once Its done so I don't have a way to chmod the file and recompile to ipa